# How to remove all R variables except the required one?

Tags: r, variables

I know these two codes will remove all the data, but what if I need only `data_1` and want to remove all other variables?

```
rm(data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, x, y, z)
rm(list=ls())
```

Comment: Try `rm(list = ls(pattern = "data_[2:4]"))`

Comment: I believe ls() has a grep argument. You could include everything except data_1

Comment: @akrun I've added few more variables in the question, now what ? is there any way doing it without typing each and every variable ?

Comment: `setdiff(ls(),"data1")`

Comment: This works also : `rm(list = ls()[!ls() %in% "data_1"])` if you want to keep only `data_1` but `setdiff()` is much better and clearer.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks a lot man !   rm(list =setdiff(ls(),"data1")) this helped.